# Google search parameter "cr" (restrict to country) doesn't seem to work

Tags: google-search, url-parameters

For example, this query:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=holy&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=667&site=webhp&source=lnms&tbm=isch&cr=countryUS&tbs=il:cl&sa=X&ei=XosDVaCXD8TasATItgE&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAg
```

returns results specific to the country that I'm currently in, instead of the US, although the url contains the parameter

*cr=countryUS*

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969830/how-to-filter-search-result-in-google-search-just-for-one-country?rq=1), cr should work.

It seems to be ignored, or overwritten by the current search settings (which default to search in the current region). But none of the cookies on the page seem to encode a country setting, googling the cookies (NID, OTZ, ANID,...) they all seem to be for personalizing ads.

How can I encode the request to search websites of a specific country, in google search?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question.   Rather it is a question about using Google.

Comment: It's about how to generate query strings for google search. When using google the usual way, you would choose the country in the settings, I assume.

Answer (score 1):

The only possible way of getting country specific search results seems to be on using a country specific proxy
Even on appending cr=countryUS and changing search setting region to United States only shows the results as filtered by the current region data servers (and not US servers)